# Trouble in showing SUM() value of a column

Tags: c++, sql, ms-access-2007, ado

Hello my fellow colleagues from StackOverflow!

I will be brief, and cut to the point:

I work on Windows XP, in C++, using ADO to access an MS Access 2007 database.

I have a table in MS Access 2007 which contains 2 columns of interest titled as TypeOfObject and InstaledPower.

The actual table looks something like this:

```
   | TypeOfObject | InstaledPower |
   -------------------------------
   |     Type1    |     1000      |
   -------------------------------
   |     Type2    |     2000      |
   -------------------------------
   |     Type3    |      450      |
   -------------------------------
   |     Type4    |      800      |   
   -------------------------------
   |     Type1    |      800      |  
   -------------------------------
```

I need a query that displays TypeOfObject and sum( InstaledPower ) for that type, in this manner:

If value of TypeOfObject is Type1 or Type2, than show it's value in table unchanged, else mark it as OtherTypes. The result should be like this:

```
   | TypeOfObject | SUM(InstaledPower) |
   -------------------------------------
   |     Type1    |     1800           |  <--- 1000 + 800 = 1800
   -------------------------------------
   |     Type2    |     2000           |  <--- only one Type2, so it is 2000
   -------------------------------------
   |   OtherTypes |     1250           |  <--- sum( InstaledPower ) of Type3 and Type4
   ------------------------------------
```

I have tried with this query:

```
   SELECT TypeOfObject , 
   SUM( InstaledPower  ) as [SUM(InstaledPower)] 
   FROM MyTable
   group by TypeOfObject  ;
```

but I get this:

```
   | TypeOfObject | SUM(InstaledPower) |
   -------------------------------------
   |     Type1    |     1800           | <--- correct
   -------------------------------------
   |     Type2    |     2000           |
   -------------------------------------
   |     Type3    |      450           | <--
   -------------------------------------    |-- this isn't what I need, see above
   |     Type4    |      800           | <--  
   -------------------------------------
```

I have tried browsing through SO archive, and found similar things, but nothing to help me.

By searching through Internet, I have come to the conclusion that this problem might be solved with pivot tables, but I do not know how to use them properly.If that is the case, if pivot table can solve this, some links would be greatly appreciated.

If there is anything else that I can do to help, ask and I will gladly do it.

Thanks to everybody who tries to help.

Comment: This isn't brief at all [sscce](http://sscce.org)

Comment: I couldn't have made it shorter, although I have tried...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
SELECT IIF(TypeOfObject in('Type1', 'Type2'), TypeOfObject, 'OtherTypes') as TypeOfObject , 
       SUM( InstaledPower  ) as [SUM(InstaledPower)] 
       FROM MyTable
 group by IIF(TypeOfObject in('Type1', 'Type2'), TypeOfObject, 'OtherTypes')
```

;

I am not sure if this syntax works in Access 2007, some databases prefer `case` expression instead of `IIF()`.

It is important, however, to repeat the first expression in the select list exactly in the group by.

Comment: I have changed the alias, since Access complained, but when I run the query in Access, a dialog box shows up asking for parameter value for Type1.I have tried entering Type1, and another dialog box showed up. Same thing as before, but parameter is for Type2, so I have entered Type2.The query then runs, but the result is incorect.Any thoughts of why this is happening?Should I edit the question and post code/screenshot?

Comment: This is my query. I have changed names of the tables in my question for better clarity: SELECT IIF( Тип_објекта in(‘Домаћинства’, ‘Саобраћај’), Тип_објекта, 'OtherTypes') as [Тип објекта] , 
       SUM( Инсталисана_топлотна_снага  ) as [SUM(InstaledPower)] 
       FROM Објекат
 group by IIF( Тип_објекта in(‘Домаћинства’, ‘Саобраћај’), Тип_објекта, 'OtherTypes');
It is the same as yours, I think.I just can't find a mistake right now...

Comment: I have retyped the field names again, and it worked! All i need to do now, is try it in my C++ code. I had troubles before using IIF, but hopefully it will work now...

Comment: @FrankPl, Thank you very much for your help, you have +1 from me!

Answer (score 0):

```
   SELECT TypeOfObject , 
   SUM(IIF(TypeOfObject = 'Type1', InstaledPower, 0)) as [Type1Sum],
   SUM(IIF(TypeOfObject = 'Type2', InstaledPower, 0)) as [Type2Sum],
   SUM(IIF(TypeOfObject <> 'Type2' 
           AND TypeOfObject <> 'Type2', InstaledPower , 0)) as [OtherTypeSum]
   FROM MyTable
   group by TypeOfObject;
```

[You might still need to pivot the rows.]

Comment: After trying it in Access I get this error message:Select statement includes a reserved word or an argument name that is misspelled or missing or punctuation is incorrect.I have added brackets behind SUM, and changed != to <>.I really don't know why it is reporting error.

Comment: I had missing ")" at end of sum statement. Please try again.

Comment: I have corrected it in the first place, it is then when it reported an error.

Comment: This is the error message I get: The Select statement includes a reserved word or an argument name that is misspelled

Comment: You have a sharp eye!When I run the query in Access, a dialog box shows up asking for parameter value for Type1.I have tried entering Type1, and another dialog box showed up. Same thing as before, but parameter is for Type2, so I have entered Type2.The query then runs, and the result is corect.Any thoughts of why this is happening?Should I edit the question and post code/screenshot?

Comment: I run this query in Access 2010  against an empty table with the same columns and it worked fine.

Comment: It were the quotes that made the problem! Fixed it, your query works. I just have to incorporate it in my C++ code. You have +1 from me! Thank you!

Comment: It was my mistake. I copied the answer into Word, edited it, and then pasted into Access.After typing it from scratch everything worked.

Comment: Before I accept it I nned to run it through my C++ code.I had issues with IIF and ADO before, so I have to be sure. Please be patient, I have upvoted your answer already.

Comment: THANK you for your solution, as I have said, you have +1 from me. The only reason I have accepted Franks solution is because it produces the exact output I need. Your solution produces a column for each TypeOfObject, yet I needed only one column for that. I wish if I could accept your solution as well but this site doesn't allow me to do so, thus the only thing I could have done is to upvote it, which I did. Thank you so much Mitch, I appreciate your help!